# Highlight Data Points Conditionally with Custom Colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to conditionally format points to be red if they're less than 20 miles per gallon, and green if they're greater than 20 mpg. This works (but not the colors I want).

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = cut(mpg, c(-Inf, 20, Inf))), size = 5)
```

As soon as I get fancy and try to select my own color scheme things break.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = cut(mpg, c(-Inf, 20, Inf))), size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "mpg",
                     values = c("(-Inf, 20]" = "red",
                                "(20, Inf]" = "green"),
                     labels = c("<= 20", "> 20"))
```

I found other examples on stackoverflow that follow the same template, but this doesn't work. I get this error and all points below 20 mpg are removed.

> Warning message: Removed 18 rows containing missing values
>   (geom_point).

Comment: Very odd, if I change the fourth line item to `values = c("(-Inf,20]" = "red",` basically eliminating one space, then everything works fine. The answer below works as well so I'll leave everything as is.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390250/in-r-when-does-spacing-matter) explains the spacing issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = cut(mpg, c(-Inf, 20, Inf))), size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "mpg",
                     values = c("red",
                                "green"),
                     breaks = c("(-Inf,20]",
                                "(20, Inf]"),
                     labels = c("<= 20", "> 20"))
```

Put the intervals in the "breaks" argument.

Comment: The legend only lists the green points. How do we get the red points on there?

Comment: `as.character(unique(cut(mtcars$mpg, c(-Inf, 20, Inf))))` There is a typo in the red label. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It works, why? `breaks = c("(-Inf,20]"` displays the correct label. `breaks = c("(-Inf, 20]"` does not. Only difference. One space. And I thought spaces were just visual aids without meaning in R. ??

Comment: I think something is going on when the 'factor' is being converted to a 'character'. It has inconsistent spacing. Spaces are not placeholders in character strings.