# In R - When Does Spacing Matter?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When does spacing matter?

`c(3, 5)` is no different then `c(3,5)`

Two examples below. Please focus on the `values = c("(-Inf,17]"...` section. The spacing of this section produces wildly different results when I place spaces between Inf, 17, and 19. *What is R doing?* There must be a logic behind the spacing eliminating values that I just can't figure out. Try the two examples below and notice the different results.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = cut(qsec, c(-Inf, 17, 19, Inf))),
               size = 5) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "qsec",
                       values = c("(-Inf,17]" = "black",
                                  "(17,19]" = "yellow",
                                  "(19, Inf]" = "red"),
                       labels = c("<= 17", "17 < qsec <= 19", "> 19"))
```

vs

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = cut(qsec, c(-Inf, 17, 19, Inf))),
               size = 5) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "qsec",
                       values = c("(-Inf, 17]" = "black",
                                  "(17,19]" = "yellow",
                                  "(19, Inf]" = "red"),
                       labels = c("<= 17", "17 < qsec <= 19", "> 19"))
```

Comment: Those spaces are inside character values (string literals, in other languages?) So they will always be interpreted exactly as you typed them. The latter version is simply using the wrong values. Those aren't the levels returned by `cut`.

Comment: `(-Inf, 17]` is not returned by `cut` - so when you use that as your label ggplot is unable to match the colour you selected. it would be the same if you had used `"apple" = "black"`

Comment: If you are matching strings, spaces matter; those are literal spaces in the string and `"(-Inf,17]"` is not equal to `"(-Inf, 17]"`. As far as the parser is concerned, the stuff in the quotes is just a thing. When you are specifying the cuts levels the parser is reading what you **don't** put in quotes and interpreting it. There spaces don't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the plots are different is because the values are the names of the levels *you* defined:

```
> cut(mtcars$qsec, c(-Inf, 17, 19, Inf)) -> my_factor
> levels(my_factor)
[1] "(-Inf,17]" "(17,19]"   "(19, Inf]"
```

So the values in the color scale need to match up, otherwise how would R know?

E.g., what if you had two levels named `"(-Inf,17]"` and `"(-Inf, 17]"`?  If R ignored the space, how would R know which factor you refer to?